# Iterate over vectors with n and n*n elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

I have this Google test assertions

```
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[0], shorterVector[0]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[1], shorterVector[1]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[2], shorterVector[2]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[3], shorterVector[0]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[4], shorterVector[1]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[5], shorterVector[2]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[6], shorterVector[0]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[7], shorterVector[1]);
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[8], shorterVector[2]);
```

as you can see, there are two vectors, shorter with n elements and longer with n*n elements (in this case 3 and 9 respectively).

How could I create two nested for loops, which would make my code shorter and simpler?

I tried for example this but it failed. I understand why but I was not able to come up with anything better.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < shorterVector.size(); i++)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < shorterVector.size(); j++)
    {
        ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector(i*j), shorterVector(j);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help and I apologize for maybe a dumb question.

Comment: One loop (size `n*n`) is enough: `ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector(i), shorterVector(i % n);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < longerVector.size(); i++)
{
        ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[i], shorterVector[i%3]);  
}
```

Comment: I would calculate `n` instead of setting it to `3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < shorterVector.size(); i++)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < shorterVector.size(); j++)
    {
        ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[i*shorterVector.size() + j], shorterVector[j]);
    }
}
```

You should assert before that `shorterVector.size() * shorterVector.size() == longerVector.size()`.

If you do not want to have the multiplication in the inner loop body you can do:

```
for(size_t i = 0, k = 0; i < shorterVector.size(); i++)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < shorterVector.size(); j++)
    {
        ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(longerVector[k++], shorterVector[j]);
    }
}
```